# How do I place a small paragraph to the right in between a text article

Tags: html, css

I want to place a quote and want to show this in between the text article. Like the one shown in the screenshot. Somewhere to the right side.[image]

[DEMO CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/42qk3o6b/)

HTML:

```
<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>
<p class="side">This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side.</p>
<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.his text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  position: relative;
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 200px
}
```

Any idea how to go about this? I'm at lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.side {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}

p {text-align: justify;}
```

```html
<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties.<span class="side">This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side.</span> The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>

<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.his text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>
```

Comment: If you put `p{  text-align:justify; }`, it will look exactly as the OP wants :)

Comment: @Alorika Thank you, I've added it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this for small paragraph to the right in between a text article:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
.side {
  float: right;
  margin: 4%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties.<span class="side"><b>This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side. This is the block I want to place at the side.</b></span> The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>

<p>This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.his text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link. This text is styled with some of the text formatting properties. The heading uses the text-align, text-transform, and color properties. The paragraph is indented, aligned, and the space between characters is specified. The underline is removed from this colored "Try it Yourself" link.</p>
```